# How to assign to variables to a split string with specific indeces?

Tags: javascript

If I have a string,

```
const string = 'This is a value and this is a field'
```

How can I destructure the term `value` and the term `field` after splitting the string?

Something like,

```
const [theValue, theField] = string.split(" ")[3][8]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're intent on using destructuring, it's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it, it looks *really* confusing:

```js
const string = 'This is a value and this is a field'
const [,,,theValue,,,,, theField] = string.split(" ");
console.log(theValue, theField);
```

This is possible because when destructuring iterables, listing values is *optional*. Similarly, you can do:

```
const [, one] = [0, 1]
```

to put `1` into the variable named `one`.

De-sugared, the first code is equivalent to:

```js
const string = 'This is a value and this is a field'
const splits = string.split(" ");
const [
  firstWord,
  secondWord,
  thirdWord,
  theValue,
  fifthWord,
  sixthWord,
  seventhWord,
  eighthWord,
  theField
] = string.split(" ");
console.log(theValue, theField);
```

(except that the variables except `theValue` and `theField` are not declared in the first code)

It would be more sensible to match non-space characters and then extract the 3rd and 8th indicies of the resulting array:

```js
const string = 'This is a value and this is a field';
const words = string.match(/\S+/g);
const theValue = words[3];
const theField = words[8];
console.log(theValue, theField);
```

(matching non-space characters with `\S+` instead of splitting on a space will be have more dependable results - using `.split` can result in empty strings leading or trailing when there's any leading or trailing whitespace)

Comment: CertainPerformance always with the fire. Thank you, it'll only be confusing to me, considering only my eyes will be seeing this code :)

Comment: what is the logic behind that `,,,` before theValue and `,,,,,` before *theField*?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks but As you can see to get the fourth you used `,,,` three comma's but after that there is only 4 words upto last value then why `,,,,,` five comma's to get the last item? or will it ignore the taken word? That means it did not calculated `theValue` that's why?

Comment: Yes understand! It doesnot calculate the `theValue` that's why it needs!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Indeces start at 0 in Javascript :)

Comment: @MikeK Yes well aware about that! What I thought that if you `destruct` a word from array it calculate itself a item so you can use next index to access next word. but that's not case here, you just destruct and ignore and start from that index to get the next value!